# rsyslog not working

Tags: centos, rsyslog

I have been trying to start the rsyslog service on centos 7 but I wont work. Please see te configuration file-

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 10544


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
        # ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

Also below is the netstat output. No where I can see the rsyslog service running:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5903            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3124/Xvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4368/X
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3124/Xvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      996/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2697/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1261/master
tcp6       0      0 :::6001                 :::*                    LISTEN      4368/X
tcp6       0      0 :::6003                 :::*                    LISTEN      3124/Xvnc
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      996/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      2697/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1261/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39924           0.0.0.0:*                           654/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           716/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           645/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           654/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58092           0.0.0.0:*                           716/dhclient
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           645/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                645/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                645/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::46946                :::*                                716/dhclient
[root@localhost etc]#
```

Comment: How did you attempt to start the service?

Comment: service rsyslog start !

Answer (score 3):

Try to check rsyslog conf with: `rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslog.conf -N 1`
If everything  is ok , try to restart `systemd-journald.socket` with:

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket
```

you can use the command `logger` to check if `rsyslog` started or not:

```
logger "hello"
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have SELinux enabled and it's blocking rsyslogd from binding to the non-standard syslog port 10544 you chose for the tcp listener. Disable SELinux completely or execute the following and restart rsyslog:

```
semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp 10544
```

There also could be errors in any included configuration files in /etc/rsyslog.d Execute the following to check config files while rsyslogd is not running:

```
rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslog.conf -N 1
```